# Can every genus $2$ curve be written as ramified cover of elliptic curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $C$ is a curve of genus $2$, does $C$ admit a surjective morphism onto some elliptic curve $E$?

Comment: Not necessarily; every map from C to an abelian variety factors through the Jacobian, and there will be a map from the Jacobian of C to an elliptic curve iff the Jacobian of C is isogenous to a product of two elliptic curves. And every abelian surface is the Jacobian of a genus 2 curve, so just choose a curve corresponding to an abelian surface that isn't isogenous to the product of two elliptic curves.

Comment: Looks to me as if $y^2=x^5-1$ does the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dhy's comment is correct, of course. You can also see that the answer is "no" by dimension counting. Fix a degree $d$. By a Riemann-Hurwitz computation, a degree $d$ cover of a genus $1$ curve by a genus $2$ curve is ramified over $2$ points (or doubly ramified over one point.) Given a positive integer $d$, a genus $1$ curve $E$ and two points $p$ and $q$, there are finitely many covers $X \to E$ of degree $d$ ramified only over $p$ and $q$. (Since each of them comes from one of finitely many maps $\pi_1(E \setminus \{ p,q \}) \to S_d$.) So, for fixed $d$, such covers are described by some finite covering of $M_{1,2}$.

Now, $\dim M_{1,2} = 2$. So, for each $d$, we get a surface of such genus $2$ curves and, as $d$ varies, we get countably many such surfaces. Counteably many surfaces can't fill up the three-fold $M_2$.

Comment: Good answer over $\mathbb C$, but the countability argument doesn't work over $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$. Nor if one wants an example defined over $\mathbb Q$.